# SQLite - Selecting based on percentage of total

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table
  WHERE ip IN (SELECT ip FROM my_table WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4))
  GROUP BY id
  HAVING SUM(count) >= 10
```

Rather than hard code it to require sum(count) >= 10, I want it to be sum(count) is >= 10% of the entire sum of the count column for that id (ie. without the "WHERE ip IN ..." constraint)

Is this possible within such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a subquery to get the 10%:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table
WHERE ip IN (SELECT ip FROM my_table WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4))
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(count) >= (SELECT 0.1 * SUM(t.count) FROM my_table t WHERE t.id = my_table.id)
```

Comment: Won't that subquery provide SUM(count) across the entire table? I need it for each particular id being tested.